# Map POST response to different object - RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to POST an object (class CompletedTest) and then parse the returned object (class Response) using RestKit 10.0. Sadly, RestKit tries to map the returned object to the class of the posted object.

If I use this code:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:tempCA delegate:self];
```

I get an error:

```
Expected an object mapping for class of type 'CompletedAssessment', provider returned one for 'Response'
```

If I use the block code to specify a mapping route

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:tempCA usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.objectMapping = [PLMapper responseMapper];
}];
```

I get the same error;

Googling around, it seems adding this to the block should help:

```
loader.targetObject = nil;
```

This does remove the error, but no objects are mapped -- the array returned contains 0 objects.

My mappers are all contained in a helper class, PLMapper, which contains around 20 mappers, all of which work in other contexts, including the responseMapper in other contexts.

Interestingly, if I take the objectMapping code out of the block:

```
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:tempCA usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.targetObject = nil;
    loader.delegate = self;
}];
```

I get a crash in RestKit RKObjectMappingOperations.m on line 329, thread 11, breakpoint 1.1

```
value = [self.sourceObject valueForKeyPath:attributeMapping.sourceKeyPath];
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here! Help much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but can you create a new Response object and set it as loader.targetObject = newResponseObject; ?

Comment: Tried making a new Response object and setting it as the targetObject -- still nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: No, it just isn't what that api is intended for. You'll need to use the lower level api to send and receive the request.

Comment: Wain can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't really use the old RestKit so I can't give an example, but probably using RKManagedObjectLoader. 0.2 RestKit doesn't explicitly do what you want either but it offers a number of classes that you could use to make the request differently.